# Comment section in django blog won't show up under each individual post?

Tags: python, html, django, blogs

The comment successfully saves in the django admin but won't show up on the actual site.

Here is the comment model:

```
class comment(models.Model):
    linkedpost = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="postcomments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    commentauthor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

This the html code for the blog home. the post for loop goes through all the post objects and prints them out. I created a comment loop to loop through all the comments for the linked post and print. Is the problem in my html code?

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <article class="media content-section">
        <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
      <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
          <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
          <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
        </div>
        <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
        <div>
            <h2>Comments</h2>
            {% for cmnts in linkedpost.postcomments %}
                #<a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' cmnts.author.username %}">{{ cmnts.commentauthor }}</a>
                <small class="text-muted">{{ cmnts.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
                <p class="article-content">{{ cmnts.body }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It should be `{% for cmnts in post.postcomments.all %}`

Answer (score 1):

The `Post` object is named `post` in the `{% for post in posts %}` loop, so you access the comments with:

```
{% for cmnts in post.postcomments.all %}
    …
{% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`comment`</s> to `Comment`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.